# Material-UI: How to disable previous dates in the datetime-local TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My objective is to disable the past days and should not allow you to select, I've tried but didn't worked.

Here is the code:

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  id="datetime-local"
  label="Select Date and Time"
  placeholder="Select Date and Time"
  type="datetime-local"
  value={this.state.DateTime}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
  onChange={this.HandleChange}
/>
```

Don't know where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help me in this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the previous date, you can use the [`min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/min) attribute of `input`. Here is how you disallow dates before `2021-02-20T00:00`:

```js
<TextField
  type="datetime-local"
  inputProps={{
    min: "2021-02-20T00:00"
  }}
/>
```

To disable previous dates, you can instantiate a new `Date` object, which defaults to current date and pass it to the `min` attribute:

```js
<TextField
  type="datetime-local"
  inputProps={{
    // only needs the first 16 characters in the date string
    min: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16),
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67032222/unable-to-disable-previous-dates-in-the-datetime-local-textfield]

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! for helping me in this query